# Set project ant classpath programatically

Tags: java, ant

I'm working on a Java project that exec Ant target task on runtime.
On my pom file I have this dependency:

**pom.xml**

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
        <version>${ant.version}</version>
     </dependency>
```

I have to run <scp> task that is included in a target container task (called scp-test-target).
Below you can see the ant file:

**deploy.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="test" basedir="./">

    <target name="scp-test-target" description="scp desc">
        <echo message="Test SCP"/>
        <scp file="..." todir="..."/>
    </target>

</project>
```

I have created a junit file to exec 'scp-test-target':

**Test.java**

```
 @Test
 public void testAnt1(){
 Project antProject = new Project();
 ProjectHelper projectHelper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
 antProject.addReference("ant.projectHelper", projectHelper);
 antProject.setUserProperty("ant.file", "deploy.xml");

 antProject.fireBuildStarted();
 antProject.init();
 projectHelper.parse(antProject, new File("deploy.xml"));
 antProject.executeTarget("scp-test-target");
 antProject.fireBuildFinished(null);

     }
```

But when I run my junit test, the program failed because it not find jsch library.

```
Problem: failed to create task or type scp
Cause: the class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp was not found.
        This looks like one of Ant's optional components.
```

So, how can I tell to Ant  to link jsch libraries on my file system in programmatically way (so in my Test.java)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *So, how can I tell to Ant to link jsch libraries on my file system in programmatically way (so in my Test.java)?* Why do you need to do it programmatically when you have deploy.xml?

Comment: Because this is a software product is sold to clients.
We don't want that clients do a lot of updates on ant file (deploy.xml).
We would to add libraries in Ant Classpath dinamically and programmatically. So, in my Java program  I would link Ant to an external folder that contains jar libs.

Comment: I still don't get it. Since the supporting libraries would be shipped and placed by you, why would you *not* know where they are and thus specify    this in the config?

Comment: The libraries would be shipped and placed by client. A client can choose what libraries put in classpath Ant.

Comment: That location can and *should* be specified by you or you will open yourself up to a lot of wholly unnecessary trouble.

Comment: The location where libraries are located is configurable by client through property. So I ask if there is a way to load this path where jars are located dynamically and programmatically.

Comment: You might need to set a classpath including these libraries *before* executing Ant programmatically. That would probably mean in effect that you need to execute *another Java process programmatically* but as I said, I think this is very much an unnecessary complication

Comment: So just to be clear, you're expecting the client to provide jsch.jar on their own file system? What if they have an incompatible version, or a version that behaves differently? You should include the jar that you've tested as a necessary runtime dependency in whatever you're shipping out to people. This approach makes no sense.